# google-youtube plays before paper-dialog-behavior is opened

Tags: javascript, youtube, polymer, polymer-1.0

*Polymer 1.0*

I have this custom element  I made for playing youtube videos. It works great. But there two issues:

1. the youtube video starts playing as soon as the index.html loads,
   rather than waiting for the `paper-dialog-behavior` to open.
2. closing the `paper-dialog-behavior` doesn't stop the video. I tried
       using the `pause` api for the `google-youtube` node but that is not
       a real fix(video should stop instead).

I could use the `google-youtube` api `play()` for the event listener `'iron-overlay-opened'`, but the `play()` method is not compatible with most android browsers and will create issues.

How can I make the `google-youtube` element play only when `paper-dialog-behavior` opens and not on initial load? And same with dismissing the `paper-dialog-behavior`.

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/google-youtube/google-youtube.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-dialog/paper-dialog.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-dialog-behavior/paper-dialog-behavior.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/neon-animation/animations/fade-out-animation.html">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/neon-animation/animations/scale-up-animation.html">
<link rel="import" type="css" href="../bower_components/paper-dialog-behavior/paper-dialog-common.css">
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/paper-styles/paper-styles.html">

<dom-module id="video-player">
  <style>
     :host {
      @apply(--layout-fit);
     }
  </style>


  <template>
    <div id="insertVideoPlayer" class="layout vertical fit">
      <google-youtube style="height: 100%"
        video-id="YMWd7QnXY8E"
        rel="1"
        start="5"
        playsinline="0"
        controls="2"
        showinfo="0"
        width="100%"
        height="100%"
        autoplay="1">
      </google-youtube>
    </div>
     <paper-button dialog-dismiss style="color: white; margin-top: 0px">
      <paper-icon-button icon="arrow-back"></paper-icon-button>
    </paper-button>
  </template>

  <script>
    Polymer({
      is: "video-player",
      behaviors: [ Polymer.PaperDialogBehavior ],
      listeners: { 'iron-overlay-closed': 'bar' },
      bar: function(e) {
        console.log('hi');
        this.$$('google-youtube').pause();
      }
    });
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: LOAD & PLAY are usually 2 separate events. Doing both as 'auto' on page load is a bit less common due to preemptory nature of pages that just go to PLAY onload(). Its chromecast element ( not YT) but u may get something out of the control bar and the playbutton... look at 'polymer.ready() '  https://github.com/googlecast/cast-button-polymer/blob/master/cast-button-polymer.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `autoplay="1"` or else the `<google-youtube>` player will start playback immediately on desktop browsers.

The `playsupported` property is set to `true` on platforms that support calling `play()` (desktop browsers) and `false` on platforms that don't (most mobile browsers). See [the docs](http://googlewebcomponents.github.io/google-youtube/components/google-youtube/) for more info.

You can check for `playsupported` and call `play()` within the `iron-overlay-opened` event if it's supported. If it's not supported, well, you can't automatically start playback.

Calling `pause()` to stop playback is recommended. While the underlying YouTube Player API supports a `stopVideo()` method, it's something of a last resort and leaves the player in an inconsistent state, which makes it less than ideal if you're going to start playing back a new video later. (See [the Player API docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#stopVideo) for more info.) For this reason, `stopVideo()` isn't exposed on `<google-youtube>`.

Comment: Do you know how https://events.google.com/io2015/ is doing it? They use the `google-youtube` element also. I need `autoplay="1"` otherwise the flow of it looks messed up when opening `paper-dialog-behavior`

Comment: I do know, as I worked on that project :-) It uses Polymer 0.5 and `<template if>` to conditionally stamp out the `<google-youtube>` element to the light DOM. https://github.com/GoogleChrome/ioweb2015/blob/e33352f89034e77f54afdb1fc685439f3962803a/app/templates/about.html#L85 If you're going to only conditionally include the element then `autoplay` is okay, but at the same time, what I suggested was a more general solution.

Comment: I was under the impression `paper-dialog-behavior` was being used and the `open()` behavior was opening the element. But that would not be the case with `<template if>` since this condition is what opens the element, correct?

Comment: If the `<google-youtube>` is wrapped in a conditional template, then it's not going to be part of the light DOM until that condition is `true`. It won't start autoplaying until it's added to the light DOM. Again, there are a few different ways of accomplishing similar results.